# Increase Distance between Pyplot Markers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

Im working on a Uni Project and we have to write a function that has given 4 arguments f,a,b and h.

f is the functionhandle that is given to the function

a and b are the inclusive interval limits of the function where the plot shall be on

and h shall be the distance between two neighboured points.

I've got everything so far but i dont get how to increase or decrease the distance between neighboured points.

Thats my Code by now:

```
def plot_function_h(f,a,b,h=10**-3):
    
    interval = np.linspace(a,b)
    
    y = list()
    
    for i in range(len(interval)):
        y.append(f(interval[i]))
        
    
    plt.plot(interval,y, 'bo')
    plt.title('h-plot')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all because you are using numpy you don't need to have a loop. You can do this:

```
y = f(interval)
```

Which is faster and easier.
Secondly np.linspace can take a lot of arguments, one of which is num, by default num is equal to 50 and it determines the number of points to generate. I think this should help you:

```
num_points = (b - a) // h
interval = np.linspace(a, b, num_points)
```

Comment: I know about the fact with the number of points in np.linspace. But is there a way to plot the points with a certain Distance to each other. I dont see how this could help.

Comment: And also when i try to use

y = f(interval)

it tells me only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars